# Create website Tab in Teams using MS Graph Java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to use Graph Api to create a tab in my Microsoft Teams Channel but I kept getting error about the program finished with non-zero exit value 1.

```
public static void createTab(){
     if (graphClient == null) throw new NullPointerException(
             "Graph client has not been initialized. Call initializeGraphAuth before calling this method");

     TeamsTab newTab = new TeamsTab();
     newTab.configuration.contentUrl = "https://www.google.com/?client=safari";
     newTab.configuration.entityId = null;
     newTab.configuration.removeUrl = null;
     newTab.configuration.websiteUrl = "https://www.google.com/?client=safari";
     newTab.displayName = "New Website Tab";

     //Post New Tab
     graphClient.teams("teams-id").channels("channel-id")
             .tabs().buildRequest().expand("teamsApp").post(newTab);

 }

This is my code, can someone please have a look?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the heck of it, try this:

````
public void createTab() {

    if (graphClient == null) throw new NullPointerException(
             "Graph client has not been initialized. Call initializeGraphAuth before calling this method");

    TeamsTab newTab = new TeamsTab();
    User me = newTab.graphClient.getMe().buildRequest().get();
        newTab.configuration.contentUrl = "https://www.google.com/?client=safari";
        newTab.configuration.entityId = null;
        newTab.configuration.removeUrl = null;
        newTab.configuration.websiteUrl = "https://www.google.com/?client=safari";
        newTab.displayName = "New Website Tab";

        //Post New Tab
        newTab.graphClient.getMe().teams("teams-id").channels("channel-id")
                .getTab().buildRequest().post();

    }
    ```
````

Comment: "teamsApp@odata.bind" I'm not sure how to add this into my code. Do you spot any problem in my code? I'm very new to Graph

Comment: I am looking over it. It may take a while.

Comment: I'm not sure the code itself is the issue. It appears you need to make the request for the tab to be inserted to the channel using this:

`POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/tabs`

Once that step is complete you send a request (the code you wrote) and if it's successful they will add the tab for you and you'll get the response message.

Comment: Ya but I'm developing with Java so I used      graphClient.teams("teamsid").channels("channel- id").tabs().buildRequest().expand("teamsApp").post(newTab);

Comment: But I'm not sure whether this is the correct way to do it as the documentation just show POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/tabs

Comment: Is it possible to include POST /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/tabs in my java code?

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Intellij

Comment: According to the walkthrough, it seems like this is how you do it:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/tabs
{
  // Your code here
  }
}```

Comment: I tried it and it seem like there's is no symbol for POST graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams{id}/channels/{id}/tabs. I thought the graphClient is technically use to POST?

Comment: Here, I found this page with examples of graphClient being used:

https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/com.microsoft.graph.extensions.IUserRequestBuilder/buildRequest

Comment: But I'm trying to add a tab to Teams is it the same?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the experience to help you. I think the main thing to take away from the tabnine link is how to use graphClient correctly. This line specifically seems to be how you call the request with Java:

`newTab.graphClient.getMe().buildRequest().get();`

But I'm not 100% sure how to incorporate it with your code.

Comment: Is fine! Hopefully the Microsoft Team able to solve my problem.Thanks!